# bipartite graph matching exercise

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

I have a problem here and would appreciate your help.

> I have a bipartite graph $G = (A \cup B,E)$ which has a matching $M$ of size $|A|$. We need to prove there's a vertex in $A$ such that each edge that contains this vertex belongs to some matching of size $|A|$.

We tried using induction; we also tried using Hall's theorem and separating two cases (when $|N(X)|>|X|$ for some subset $X$ of $A$, or $|N(X)|=|X|$) but got stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that there is a similar (but simpler) property for arbitrary graphs (where the vertex is not required to belong to $A$): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371137/property-of-maximum-matching .

Answer (score 3):

Assume the contrapositive, i.e. every vertex $v$ has an edge $e_v$ that does not belong
to any matching of size $|A|$.

Let $v_1$ be a vertex of $A$, $w_1$ the vertex of $B$ that is the other endpoint of $e_{v_1}$.
$w_1$ must be saturated by $M$, or we can exchange the edge of $M$ that saturates $v_1$ by $v_1w_1$
to get a matching of size $|A|$ that contains $e_{v_1}$.
Now let $v_2$ be the vertex of $A$ that is the other endpoint of the edge of $M$ that saturates $w_1$.
Let $w_2$ be the endpoint of $e_{v_2}$ etc.

We get a path that starts at $v_1$, alternates between edges that are in no matching of size $\left|A\right|$
and edges of $M$. Such a path must close eventually.

On the resulting cycle swap both types of edges and you get a matching of size $\left|A\right|$ containing
several of the $e_v$ edges. Contradiction.

Comment: nicely done! thanks!