# Property of maximum matching

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matching-theory

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with no perfect matching.
>   Then there exists a vertex $v$ such that every incident edge (i.e., every edge incident to $v$) is part of a maximum matching.

I'm not sure how to prove this. How can every edge that coincides with $v$ be part of a maximum matching? It sounds contrary to the definition of matchings.

Comment: The incident edges aren't all part of the same maximum matching. The statement is asserting that for each incident edge, there is a maximum matching containing it.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I see that you have created ([tag:matching-theory]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/matching-theory/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. Especially since this word is used in other meanings (economics, statistics - see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34395519#34395519).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Good point. I've proposed something, but I'm not sure how well it adhers to standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This proof works for finite graphs only.**

Suppose contrary that, for every $v\in V$, there exists an edge $e_v=\left\{v,w_v\right\}$, where $w_v\in V$, such that $e_v$ is not a part of any maximum matching in $G$.   Let $M$ be a maximum matching in $G$.

Since $G$ has no perfect matchings, there is a vertex $v\in V$ not matched in $M$.  Note that $w_v$ has to be matched in $M$; otherwise $M\cup\left\{e_v\right\}$ would be a matching in $G$ strictly larger than $M$.  Suppose that, in $M$, $w_v$ is paired with $u\in V$.  Define $M':=\Big(M\setminus\big\{\left\{w_v,u\right\}\big\}\Big)\cup\left\{e_v\right\}$.  Then, $M'$ is a matching in $G$ containing $e_v$ such that $\left|M'\right|=|M|$, whence $M'$ is a maximum matching.  Thus, $e_v$ is a part of a maximum matching, a contradiction.  That is, there must exist a vertex in $G$ each of whose incidental edges belongs in a maximum matching in $G$.

Comment: You have constructively found the vertex $v$ and maximum matchings $M_e \ni e$ for any edge $e$ incident to $v$. Why do you need the contradiction, this proof would be much better without it.

Comment: You are right.  Any vertex not covered by a maximum matching has the required property.  I'm not editing my solution, though.  It is ok as it is.